# Set the offset value in lsmeans

Tags: generalized-linear-model, offset, lsmeans

I'm using a negative binomial glmm for analysis.

The y values of my samples are summed over 12 individual counts of insect mines on leaves of a tree. You can get the data (and session info) from [here](https://gist.github.com/BizarreRide/bb06a2cc0061910f2e3889eee07aff02)!.

Treat has 2 levels;
Year has 2 levels;
Habitat has 3 levels;
leaves is the same number of 12 leaves for each sample;
location has 4 levels and is almost similar to location.
Two of the locations fall in the same "habitat" category.
I use sublocation as random effect, since I want to get results for habitat not for all sublocations separately while being aware of the more similar measures at a single location.

This is the model:

```
library(MASS)
library(lme4)
library(optimx)

glmm1 <- glmer.nb(response ~ year*(Habitat+Treat) + offset(log(leaves)) + (1|location), data = df1, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", calc.derivs = FALSE, optCtrl = list(method = "nlminb", starttests = FALSE, kkt = FALSE)))
```

Now I use the following code to create a prediction plot:

```
# Prediction plot
predframe <- expand.grid(year= levels(df1$year),
                         Habitat= levels(df1$Habitat),
                         Treat= levels(KMM2$Treat),
                         leaves = 10) # Set the offset!!
```

Here I am able to alter the offset to get results for the more commonly used reference of 10 leaves !

```
mm <- model.matrix(~ year*(Habitat + Treat) + offset(log(leaves)), data = predframe)

predframe$fit <- predict(glmm1,newdata=predframe, re.form = NA) # Don't use type="response"!!!
# Alternatively use: predframe$fit <- mm %*% fixef(glmm1)

pvar1 <- diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(glmm1),mm))
# alternatively use: pvar1 <- diag(mm %*%vcov(glmm1) %*% t(mm)) 
tvar1 <- pvar1+VarCorr(glmm1)$Standort[1] # must be adapted for more complex models
predframe <- data.frame(predframe
                        , p_lwr = predframe$fit-1.96*sqrt(pvar1) # for confidence interval
                        , p_upr = predframe$fit+1.96*sqrt(pvar1)
                        , t_lwr = predframe$fit-1.96*sqrt(tvar1) # for prediciton interval
                        , t_upr = predframe$fit+1.96*sqrt(tvar1)
)

predframe2 <- aggregate(cbind(fit, p_lwr, p_upr) ~ year + Treat,predframe, mean)

ggplot(aes(y=interaction(year, Treat), x=exp(fit)), data=predframe2) + geom_point() +
        geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=exp(p_upr), xmin=exp(p_lwr)))
```

Here I use the lsmeans package to do the same:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsm.options(save.ref.grid = TRUE)
lsm <- lsmeans(glmm1, ~ Netz*Jahr, offset=10)
.Last.ref.grid
```

Offset was not adjusted to 10!

```
plot(cld(lsm, type="response"))
```

Besides slightly different confidence intervals (why?) these results are the same as if I used leaves=12 for the `predframe` above

How can I adjust the offset  in lsmeans?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the `ksmeans` function does not have an `offset` argument. That might explain why it has no effect. Meanwhile, the offset in the model formula *is* included in the calculations. To see what is used, look at `lsm@grid`

Comment: Oops, typo in above. Of course I meant `lsmeans` where it says `ksmeans`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Yes, you are right, the reference grid uses the offset variable (.Last.ref.grid). I knew this. But, if I understand you right, the offset value can't be changed? My case is simple, I've got the same offset value for all samples, but how is it when sb uses different values? the use of an offset might be useless then? I used offset to adjust predictions when samples are from different volumes, plot size, etc.

Comment: You can use `at` to specify different `leaves` value(s). Note that `leaves` is one of the variables in the reference grid, and it is used to calculate the offset.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works, thanks to rvl!!

```
lsm.options(save.ref.grid = TRUE)
lsm <- lsmeans(glmm1, ~ Treat*year, at=list(leaves=10))
.Last.ref.grid
plot(cld(lsm, type="response", sort=FALSE))
```

Now the reference grid is similar to the prediction frame above.

However: same same but different! Here are the two plots from both different procedures. I PREFER THE ONE FROM lsmeans!!!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: `plot(lsm, type = "response")` will do the same thing more efficiently, because the compact-letter-display calculations don't play a role in the resulting plot.